# SQL Table Design: Multiple foreign key columns or general "fkName" and "fkValue" columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design

Given a table (Contacts) which could apply to distinct items in a database (Employers, Churches, Hospitals, Government Groups, etc.) which are stored in different tables, when leveraging this single contacts table in the end I've found there exist two choices for relating a contact back to one particular "item"

- One column for each "item" type with a Foreign Key association, this results in a table looking like:

> ```
>   contactID empID     churchID  hospID    govID     conFN     conLN     ...
> ```

- One column indicating the type of "item" (fkName) and one column for the value corresponding to the item of that type (fkValue). This results in a table looking like:

> ```
>   contactID fkName    fkValue   conFN     conLN     ...
> ```

The first means that out of the X possible foreign keys, X-1 will be NULL, but I get the advantages of hard-associated foreign keys.

The second means that I can set fkName and fkValue as NOT NULL but I don't get the advantages of DB-supported foreign keys.

Ultimately, is there a "right" answer? Are there other advantages / disadvantages that I haven't thought about (performance, security, growth/expansion)?

Comment: No to your first idea. Yes to your second if you have a list of types.

Comment: A "general" (or "generic") approach **CANNOT** really guarantee referential integrity and thus is useless in my opinion

Answer (score 2):

The second approach is an anti-pattern.

You need to set up many-to-many relationship tables between each entity (Hospitals, Churches, Employers, Government Groups, etc.) and Contacts.

If you want to make it easier to query for all of the entities a contact is related to, consider creating a view on top of the many-to-many relationship tables.

Answer (score 1):

I think the second option is better as it will allow you to maintain referential integrity of your database using the in-built SQL features (foreign keys), rather than relying on your code to maintain it.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution that you should be going towards:

```
type
----------------
typeId  name
1       hospital
2       church

contact
-----------------------------------------
contactId firstName LastName typeId (fk)
1         bob       is       1
2         your      uncle    2
```

If Bob can be a contact for more than one type, than you will need a junction table.